# 'checkout as guest' work same as 'register' with auto generated password

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout

On onepage-checkout page there are three methods to check out.

How checkout as guest method work same register method with auto generated password?

Comment: The diction in your question is unclear. Do you mean that you would like for users who checkout as a guest to have an account created for them?

Comment: yes I mean exactly what you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest observing `customer_register_success` event and doing something like this:

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getData('customer');
/* TODO: check that registration type is 'guest'. Otherwise you overwrite inserted password */
$customer->setPassword(_your_generated_password_here_)->save();
```

Comment: will work on onepage-checkout page?
If Yes then which file I need to edit?

Comment: @ganesh Your observer. http://www.crearegroup-ecommerce.co.uk/blog/magento-tutorials/basic-magento-observer-tutorial.php